# How to shrink first TextView rather than second one if 2 TextView have long text in ConstraintLayout？

Tags: java, android, textview, android-constraintlayout

I want 2 TextView connected together. And if the first contains more text, it should shrink.
At the same time, the 2nd one should always show all the text and can not shrink. It should append to the end of the parent view, should not go out of bound
How can I achieve this?

What I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatarImg"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:riv_oval="true"
    tools:src="@mipmap/avatar_test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/peach_red"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatarImg"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result is

[image]

### Edit:

Per @Gavin Wright's answer. I also want the second one to bind to the first tightly if the text in size is short.
This is the difficult point that I can achieve this... Sorry for not mentioning in advance...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `TextView` should have `layout_width = 0dp`, as this forces it to take up only the remaining width on the line. The second `TextView` should have `layout_width = wrap_content`, as this forces it to take up as much space as needed to fit its contents. I also added    `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content`, to the first `TextView`, as this is needed to enforce the relationship between the two `TextViews`.

This is tested and works perfectly for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:paddingTop="2dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">
<com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatarImg"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:riv_oval="true"
    tools:src="@mipmap/avatar_test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/peach_red"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatarImg"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textColor="@color/black1"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please check my update for the question. Thank you!

Comment: That does indeed complicate things. It's still possible, but you'll have to do it programmatically rather than in XML. Basically, you'll have to measure the width of the `RoundedImageView` plus the [text width in the `TextViews`](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+measure+text+width+textview&oq=android+measure+text+width+&aqs=chrome.1.69i59j0l7.4928j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and determine if they are less than the screen width. If they are less, you change `nameTextView` to have `layout_width = "wrap_content"`.

Comment: I am curious whether there's an easier way or not. If not, I will mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: You can do some crazy things with `ConstraintLayout`, but in this case I think there's just too much logic to handle it in XML.